# Is it possible to call an actions function in my reducer from a route in Express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux

I have a route in Express and i'd like to call action function imported from my reducer:

```
/* initial state */
export var usersStartState = {
  isAccountVerified: false,
};

/* action types */
export const actionTypes = {
  IS_ACCOUNT_VERIFIED: 'IS_ACCOUNT_VERIFIED',
};

/* reducer(s) */
export default function users(state = usersStartState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.IS_ACCOUNT_VERIFIED:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isAccountVerified: true });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

/* actions */
export const hasBeenVerified = () => {
  return { type: actionTypes.IS_ACCOUNT_VERIFIED };
};
```

And this is my route:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/UserModel');
var Token = require('../models/TokenSchema');
import { hasBeenVerified } from '../../store/reducers/users/index';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

router.route('/confirmation/:token').get((req, res, next) => {
  var usersToken = req.params.token;
  try {
    Token.findOne({ token: usersToken }, function(err, token) {
      if (err)
        return res.status(404).send({
          type: 'not-verified',
          msg: 'We were unable to find a valid token. Your token my have expired.'
        });
      // If we found a token, find a matching user
      User.findOne({ _id: token._userId, email: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
          return res
            .status(404)
            .send({ msg: 'We were unable to find a user for this token.' });
        if (user.isVerified)
          return res.status(400).send({
            type: 'already-verified',
            msg: 'This user has already been verified.'
          });

        // Verify and save the user
        user.isVerified = true;
        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message });
          }
        });
      });
      hasBeenVerified(); // firing it here
      console.log('hasBeenVerified();', hasBeenVerified());
      res.redirect('/confirmed');
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

I've tried to set a `hasBeenVerified(); console.log('hasBeenVerified()', hasBeenVerified());`

And it does return an output in the terminal:

```
hasBeenVerified(); { type: 'IS_ACOUNT_VERIFIED' }
```

But it doesn't change the store's initial state.

```
export var usersStartState = {
  isAccountVerified: false, //still false after the `hasBeenVerified` executed
};
```

Any thoughts how to fix that?

Comment: Err, so are you using Redux in your frontend or backend?

Comment: I am using it on my frontend and backend (at least trying to lol)!

Comment: I'm not even sure how `hasBeenVerified` exists on your backend.. In short, no you cannot do this. You'll either need to respond to your front end with the necessary data so you can verify on your front end, or send the necessary data to your backend so you can verify there, and redirect, etc.. as needed. To troubleshoot further I would need to see more code... do you have this up on GitHub anywhere?

Comment: @MattOestreich I've added code in my express route to show the imports...
So that how `hasBeenVerified ` exists.

Comment: Gotcha... that makes sense how it's getting there but the reason it doesn't update your state is because React code is running in the browser and Express code is running on the server - they are not aware of eachother. You'll either need to send the appropriate state to your backend with an XHR request, or send the necessary data to your front end using the `res.send()`..

Comment: @MattOestreich Ugh of course! So could you make a example how it would be done? So would I be getting a `npm package` that does server `XHR requests i.e. axios`& which would enable me to send a request to the client? Hopefully it's obvious but I have a private route on the FE which can only be accessed if the store value—`isAccountVerified ` is true!

Comment: Yes. Give me a minute, though - may take 30 minutes or so.

Comment: @MattOestreich Thanks mate!

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz are you using Redux with hooks? Just want to build an example that mirrors what you're using.

Comment: @MattOestreich no I’m not using hooks in this project. I'm using Redux for state that's more universal and using the Class components that's local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you will need to:

- Send the necessary parts of your frontend state to your backend
- Your backend verifies using the data it was sent
- Backend responds with verification status to your frontend
- Frontend uses this verification data to update Redux

[View a live demo here](https://react-redux-express-poc.herokuapp.com/)

Below are the 'meat and potatoes' of what is needed to outline the above steps.  Although, [I have published all of the code I wrote in the following GitHub repo](https://github.com/oze4/react-express-redux-poc) - I suggest you fork it and run it locally to really get the point across..

**Backend:**

***server.js***

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 8002;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

app.post('/authorize', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.un === 'a' && req.body.pw === 'a') {
        res.status(200).send('true');
    } else {
        res.status(200).send('false');
    }
});

// For 404
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send("Unable to find that!");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

**Frontend:**

***App.js***

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from "./Routes";
import withRedux from "./Redux/containers";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    un: "",
    pw: ""
  };

  handleUnInput = event => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      un: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handlePwInput = event => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      pw: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handleLogout = () => {
      this.props.setAccountStatus(false);
  }

  handleLogin = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8002/authorize", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ un: this.state.un, pw: this.state.pw })
    })
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(data => {
        if (data === "true") {
          this.props.setAccountStatus(true);
        } else {
          alert("Incorrect credentials!");
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log("Something went wrong! " + err.message));
  };
  render() {
    const { isAccountVerified } = this.props.state;

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <br />
        <Link to="/protected">Protected</Link>
        <div style={{ margin: '40px' }}>
          {isAccountVerified ? (
            <button onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</button>
          ) : (
            <React.Fragment>
              <p>
                Try to visit the 'Protected' route above. Unless you are logged
                in it won't work.
              </p>
              Username:
              <input type="text" onInput={this.handleUnInput} />
              <br />
              Password:
              <input type="password" onInput={this.handlePwInput} />
              <br />
              <small>Username is 'a' password is 'a'</small>
              <br />
              <button onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</button>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </div>
        <Routes />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default withRedux(App);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Matt!!! I can’t wait to give it a try! I’m with my daughter for the evening, but will give it a try in the morning!

Comment: No worries! Hope y'all have a good time :) - I also went ahead and published that code on Heroku, so if you want, [you can view a live demo of the example here](https://react-redux-express-poc.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Whoa! That’s really awesome my friend! GREATLY appreciate this!!!